# Recursive syntax in haskell using and

Tags: haskell

I am trying to create a recursive function that takes and input List of List that looks like this: `[[1,2], [4], [3], [1]]` and returns a Bool. It is supposed to check whether all lists include at least one unique number. I am trying to do this recursively using the two function below.

Function that removes all elements from the first list in the second list:

```
helper :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
helper a b = filter (`notElem` b) a
```

Main function:

```
function :: [[Int]] -> Bool 
function [] = True
function (x:y:xs) = (not (null r)) and (function (r ++ xs))
    where r = helper(x,y)
```

However, I get these two errors from the compiler:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘(t0 Bool -> Bool) -> Bool -> Bool’
              with actual type ‘Bool’

The function ‘not’ is applied to three arguments,
  but its type ‘Bool -> Bool’ has only one
  In the expression: (not (null r)) and (function (r ++ xs))
  In an equation for ‘function’:
      function (x : y : xs)
        = (not (null r)) and (function (r ++ xs))
        where
            r = helper (x, y)
```

I am new to Haskell and not fully comfortable with the Haskell syntax.

Comment: `and` doesn't do what you think, you're looking for `&&`

Comment: a guess: you try to check if the second list contains any element not in the first, the third should contain one element not in the first nor the second, ...?

Comment: `helper(x,y)` is wrong since `helper` does not take a pair as argument. Use `helper x y` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First issue - calling a function with multiple arguments. This is done with the following syntax: `myFunction a b` (not `myFunction (a, b)`).

The reason for this is that `(a, b)` is a tuple. [Here's a link with some info on tuples](http://www.toves.org/books/hslist/#s1)

Second issue - you are using [and](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:and) instead of [`&&`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-38--38-)

Third issue - you are trying to combine `r` and `xs` with `++` but the type of `r` is `[Int]` whereas the type of `xs` is `[[Int]]`. If your goal is to prepend `r` to `xs` then you can do this with `:`

```
helper :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
helper a b = filter (`notElem` b) a

function :: [[Int]] -> Bool 
function [] = True
function (x:y:xs) = not (null r) && function (r : xs)
    where r = helper x y
```